# Is it possible to scrape data from the maps of this website?

Tags: python, maps, screen-scraping

Is it possible to scrape data using python from a maps from this
https://www.kiabi.com/magasins.html
I need to scrape information from each blue bullet.

I tried to look into the source code and find something with "hidden" status.

Comment: please [edit] to include your code

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information about all the shops with the following cURL command.
Don't remove the Referer header, as the server is using it for validation.

```
> curl 'https://api.woosmap.com/stores?key=woos-3246a080-0b90-39a2-a673-5ae6b9acb1d9' -H 'Referer: https://www.kiabi.com/magasins.html'
```

You may need to refresh the key parameter after some time.
You can find it hardcoded in the HTML of the url that you provided.

```
> curl -s 'https://www.kiabi.com/magasins.html' | grep -oE 'fr:woos-[0-9a-f-]{36}'
fr:woos-3246a080-0b90-39a2-a673-5ae6b9acb1d9
```